# Can we prevent IE caching beans to temp internet files directory?

Tags: java, apache-flex, caching, javabeans

Our application has a Flex front-end to Java back-end.  One of our clients has noticed files in the temporary internet files directory that contain sensitive information (ssns, names & addresses).  The files are named "OurAppName" followed by an apparently system-generated temp string, followed by ".xml".  The contents of the files are the contents of beans written by us, in an xml format.

Looking at different Fiddler traces made of our app (not taken at the client, but here at our site), I see POST transactions where the responses are our beans.  The request headers for those have "Pragma: no-cache", and the response headers have "Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, s-max-age=0,proxy=revalidate".

Is there something we can do with the cache directives?  All of the beans are declared as serializable, will that prevent us from keeping these from getting saved to disk?

I hope that is enough info, please let me know if there is more info needed.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is kind of a dumb question, but are you using http or https to serve your data?  Also, how are you connecting your Flex and Java components?  BlazeDS?  Raw URLLoader calls to your server?  Something else?

Comment: @Brian, we are using http to serve the data.  The Flex code uses a class we wrote that makes HTTP POST requests to a server where our Java code runs, to retrieve the beans.

Comment: Why are you serving sensitive information via http?!  Regardless, you could try following the advice at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067 - it doesn't look like you're sending all of the headers mentioned there.